# Trying to get the value of the id to the place holder

Tags: javascript

When clicking the address I want to get the value of the id zipcode to the placeholder. what I did wrong?

```js
function addZipcode() {
  objZipcode = document.getElementById("zipcode");
  document.getElementById("myText").value = objZipcode.value;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Zipcode: <input type="text" id="myText" placeholder="Name">
<br/>
<a onclick="addZipcode()">3 Ebsworth Cl Macarthur Act <span id="zipcode">2904</span> </a>
```

Comment: Edit post to move the question out of the code snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function addZipcode(){
objZipcode = document.getElementById("zipcode");

document.getElementById("myText").value = objZipcode.textContent;
}
```

```html
Zipcode: <input type="text" id="myText" placeholder="Name">
<br/>
<a onclick="addZipcode()">3 Ebsworth Cl Macarthur Act <span id="zipcode">2904</span> </a>
```

Comment: what if i got two or more zipcode and i want to get individual zipcode to appear on the placeholder when i click on them.

Comment: I can update the code snippet to solve the problem, but one thing that you must avoid is to have duplicate id values.

Comment: so i cant have the same id?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the span's text with `innerText`.

```js
function addZipcode(){
  let objZipcode = document.getElementById("zipcode");
  document.getElementById("myText").value = objZipcode.innerText;
}
```

```html
Zipcode: <input type="text" id="myText" placeholder="Name">
<br/>
<a onclick="addZipcode()">3 Ebsworth Cl Macarthur Act <span id="zipcode">2904</span> </a>
```

Comment: Element.innerHTML returns HTML, as its name indicates. Sometimes people use innerHTML to retrieve or write text inside an element, but textContent has better performance because its value is not parsed as HTML.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent#differences_from_innerhtml

Comment: ok will be using textContent. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        Zipcode: <input type="text" id="myText" placeholder="Name">
        <br/>
        <a onclick="addZipcode()">3 Ebsworth Cl Macarthur Act <span id="zipcode">2904</span> </a>
        <script>
            function addZipcode() {
                objZipcode = document.getElementById("zipcode").innerText;

                document.getElementById("myText").value = objZipcode;

            };
        </script>
    </body>

    </html>
```